# Get Intent from intent-filter with WebIntent Native Plugin

Tags: android, android-intent, ionic3, ionic-native

I’m working with Ionic Native Plugin Web Intent, and I want to get an android Intent and use a media file or your local url in my app. My AndroidManifest.xml it’s ok, and i can see myApp as an option for share or pick an image.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
```

But i’m locked trying to get this intent in my app.

I tried to use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/web-intent/ native plugin, but i’m getting a response error “plugin_not_installed”.

```
constructor(private _platform: Platform,
        private _webIntent: WebIntent
    ) {
    }

...

ionViewDidLoad() {
     this._platform.ready().then(() => {

            this._webIntent.getIntent().then((data: any) => {
                // Use data from intent
            }).catch((error:any) => console.log(error));
        });
}
```

Debugging with an Android version 5.0.1.

If anyone can help me! I really appreciate!

Obs.: I read https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/webintent-plugin-not-installed/96744, and I don’t see any resolution from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an Intent Filter to your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Then in your constructor, do this after your device in ready state.

```
   if (window.plugins){
      window.plugins.webintent.hasExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_STREAM,
      function(hasIt){
        if (hasIt) {
          window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_STREAM,
          function(streamData){
            console.log(streamData);
          }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
          });
        }
      },function(err){
          console.log(err);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should move `getIntent()` inside constructor.